# debug two separate java server app with intellij and payara

Tags: java, intellij-idea, payara

I want to debug two separate java server app with intellij IDEA and payara. first project run correctly but when I run second one nothing happen.

Error:

```
Error running 'glassfish': Unable to open debugger port (127.0.0.1:9009): java.net.SocketException "socket closed
```

Is there any way to do this without using two instance of payara with different port?

Comment: Did you try to run two applications from different projects or did you run them in single run/debug configuration?

Comment: @Gregory.K I have tried two applications from different projects

Comment: Do you have 2 different server configurations? IDEA is trying to start a second Payara Server instance, do you know why? Cna you configure both project to run on the same instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Glassfish Server runs as single JVM process in standalone mode. Thus, only one remote debugger can be attached at the same time.

That is why the Debugging on one JVM process is only possible from single IDEA's project. It is important to note that IDEA limits debugging scope of the source code to modules are deployed with run/debug configurations.

Also, if you try simultaneous debugging of the several applications from different projects, you should run them on different Glassfish instances with different ports as well.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate debug configuration for the second application and launch it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Using Gradle you can use the includeBuild command in settings.gradle and then you can debug different projects in the same window of IntelliJ IDEA:

*settings.gradle:*

```
includeBuild('..\otherGradleProjectFolder')
```